# What are the Twitterized Macs?

Tags: macos, catalina

Whenever I try to install MacOS Catalina which I have downloaded from App Store, It shows me that MacOS Catalina is not compatible with Twitterized Macs.

**What are the Twitterized Macs?**

[image: Catalina, macOS 10.15, is not yet compatible with Twitterized Macs.]

Macbook Specs:

- MacBook Pro 2017 (14,2)
- Core i7 3.5GHz
- 16GB RAM
- 500GB SSD

Comment: This looks like your Mac is centrally managed. Did you contact your helpdesk as indicated in the dialog box?

Comment: @nohillside Centrally managed Mac? Secondly, Prompt doesn't shows clear information that to which "go/helpdesk" should I contact. Does that mean Apple Help Desk?

Comment: The helpdesk of the company you are working for :-) If this is a Mac you bought second-hand it might still be locked onto the company it was used in before.